# EWS Managed API find items with ItemID

Tags: c#, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I am trying to find items from deleted items folder given the items unique id

```
ItemId id = new ItemId("zTK6edxaI9sb6AAAQKqWHAAA");
SearchFilter.IsEqualTo filter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.Id, id);
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Subject);
FindItemsResults<Item> results = _ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.DeletedItems, filter, view);
Console.WriteLine(results.TotalCount);
```

This code returns an exception saying:

```
Validation failed.
Parameter name: searchFilter
```

The same code works if I search for a message with Subject.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't need to use FindItems if you already know the ItemId

```
EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(StringItemId));
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to ensure the ID exists before, so that the Bind method will not except on an item that no longer exists?

Comment: This is great!  Helped me figure out folder names as well in PoweShell.

    [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId]("*************************"))

Answer (score 6):

You cannot search on a ComplexProperty such as the ItemId. I'm assuming that Item.Bind won't work due to the item being moved, which changed the ItemId?

If that's the case, then you'll need to use a SearchFilter on another property. If these are Items that you created via EWS, you could attach a unique Extended Property to each and use that if you need to search for one.

Comment: Yes the change of ItemIDs proved fatal and I realized that it is not a reliable mechanism for correlating items that were moved to some other folder like Inbox to Deleted items.

Comment: The extended property will be blatenly copied on item copy in Outlook, making the unique ID not-so-unique anymore.